# Transform an array with a delimited path key by recursion

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I want to transfer a set of arrays

```
array(
    array('path' => 'aa'), // every array includes additional data
    array('path' => 'bb'),
    array('path' => 'aa_bb'),
    array('path' => 'aa_cc'),
    array('path' => 'bb_aa'),
    array('path' => 'bb_bb'),
    array('path' => 'bb_cc'),
    array('path' => 'bb_bb_aa'),
    array('path' => 'bb_bb_bb'),
    array('path' => 'bb_bb_bb_aa'),
    array('path' => 'cc')
);
```

to the following structure.

```
array(
    array(
        array('path'=>'aa'), // every array still includes the data
        array('path'=>'aa_bb')
    ),
    array(
        array('path'=>'aa'),
        array('path'=>'aa_cc')
    ),
    array(
        array('path'=>'bb'),
        array('path'=>'bb_aa')
    ),
    array(
        array('path'=>'bb'),
        array('path'=>'bb_bb'),
        array('path'=>'bb_bb_aa')
    ),
    array(
        array('path'=>'bb'),
        array('path'=>'bb_bb'),
        array('path'=>'bb_bb_bb'),
        array('path'=>'bb_bb_bb_aa')
    ),
    array(
        array('path'=>'bb'),
        array('path'=>'bb_cc')
    ),
    array(
        array('path'=>'cc')
    )
);
```

The structure is based on the unique path key that contains the path with an underscore as a delimiter.
The underscore delimiter indicates another level within the path.

For example:
'bb_bb_aa' consists of different 3 levels 'bb','bb_bb' and 'bb_bb_aa'

The result should be an array, that contains all elements of the highest possible levels and their sublevel elements.

For example:
'bb_bb_bb_aa' and 'aa_cc' are endpoints of their path, as there are no higher level keys (eg. something like 'aa_cc_aa').
They would result into the following arrays

```
array(
    array('path'=>'bb'),
    array('path'=>'bb_bb'),
    array('path'=>'bb_bb_bb'),
    array('path'=>'bb_bb_bb_aa')
)
```

and

```
array(
    array('path'=>'aa'),
    array('path'=>'aa_cc')
)
```

The only solution that came to my mind is to change the output to an associative array with the path field value as an index, then create an array with all endpoints of the path (eg. 'aa_bb','aa_cc','bb_bb_aa','bb_bb_bb','cc') and afterwards iterate over the list to create the output array.

```
$index = array();
foreach ($input as $value) {
    $index[$value['path']] = $value;
}

$list = array();
foreach ($input as $value) {
    $prev = substr($value['path'], 0, strrpos($value['path'], '_'));
    if (isset($list[$prev])) {
        unset($list[$prev]);
    }
    $list[$value['path']] = $value['path'];
}

$out = array();
foreach ($list as $value) {
    $row = array();
    $items = explode('_', $value);
    $current = "";
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($current) {
            $item = "_" . $item;
        }
        $current .= $item;
        $row[] = $index[$current];
    }
    $out[] = $row;
}
```

Is there a more simple way to provide this (eg. by recursion)?

**Update**
Changed the index name from 'key' to 'path' and also call it 'path' instead of 'key chain'.

Comment: You gonna have to indent your code better for it to be easier to understand

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Added some more indents.

Comment: i cant understand the logic behind this, can you explain more about that required structure ? @user3333137

Comment: Added some additional explanations.
@Viral: Sorry, that I not made it clear enough in the first place

Comment: Trying to find out what you really want. First, what you call a `key` is really a 'path'. A key would be, say 'cc' and the path to it would be `'root' => 'bb'`. Do you want a full 'tree' with one 'key' per node and each node will hold the a list of reachable children. [Example at eval.in](https://eval.in/private/72c31bf59817fd). This is just your test data hard coded as a full tree. Feel free to use the stuff at `eval.in` in any way you wish.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent: Thank you very much. I was really struggeling to explain my problem. Yes, you're absolutely right, it's a path and not a key. I'll change the question to clarify this. Unfortunately a tree is not the result I'm looking for. It is more a list of all possible (full) paths including all sub elements.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31051748/3113793) is a question similar to your requirement using recursion, but i am not sure that is what you want, so below is a custom function, Also works with payload other than `key`

```
function custom_function(array $array)
{
    $exploded = explode('_', $array['key']);
    $i = count($exploded);
    while ($i > 0)
    {
        $new[] = implode('_', array_slice($exploded, 0, $i));
        $i--;
    }
    unset($array['key']);
    return array_merge(array_map(function($v){
         return ['key'=>$v]; 
        }, array_reverse($new)), $array);
}

$required = array_map('custom_function', $input);
```

Now, taking `$input` as

```
$input = array(
    array('key' => 'aa'),
    array('key' => 'bb_aa'),
    array('key' => 'bb_bb_bb'),
    array('key' => 'dd_cc_bb_aa'),
);
```

will give

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'key' => string 'aa' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'key' => string 'bb' (length=2)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'key' => string 'bb_aa' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'key' => string 'bb' (length=2)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'key' => string 'bb_bb' (length=5)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'key' => string 'bb_bb_bb' (length=8)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'key' => string 'dd' (length=2)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'key' => string 'dd_cc' (length=5)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'key' => string 'dd_cc_bb' (length=8)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          'key' => string 'dd_cc_bb_aa' (length=11)
```

Comment: Thanks Viral, even it don't exactly provides the result I expect (if I am using my input data), it's an interesting approach. 
Maybe I am able to build on it.

Comment: this is exactly what you have in expected output @user3333137

Comment: If I am using your input array this is correct. But if I am using the input array from my question, then it doesn't fit. The result should only contain all path endpoints including their sub elements. Therefore the result array should have less array elements on the root level. In my case `count($input)` is 11 while `count($output)` results in 7. As Ryan Vincent mentioned in his comment I should have called it path instead of key.

Comment: okay, got it now, i'll try with that and put my code here @user3333137